# `E1026 File not found Unit2.dfm`

Tags: android, delphi

I have a simple TCP server application that I have copied from the internet.

```
unit TCPServer;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdSocketHandle,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdContext;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Tserver: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TserverExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Binding : TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  Tserver.DefaultPort := 16000;
  Tserver.Bindings.Clear;
  Binding := Tserver.Bindings.Add;
  Binding.IP := '0.0.0.0';
  Binding.Port := 16000;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Tserver.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.TserverExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
Var
C : String;
begin
 C:= AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn();

 if C = 'TESTSTRING' then
 begin
   AContext.Connection.Socket.Writeln('SENT');
 end;


end;

end.
```

I am attempting to get it to compile on a Android device. I have created a new multidevice form `Unit2 (Unit2.pas and Unit2.fmx )`and pasted the above file inside `Unit2.pas`.

When I compile the project I get the error

`E1026 File not found Unit2.dfm`

I am brand new to delphi programming. I would like to know what is a `dfm` file. How is it different from a `fmx` file which seems to be the correct way to create a Form on my IDE.I am using `Embarcadero® Delphi 10 Seattle`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Firemonkey doesn't use `dfm` files. It uses `fmx` files. `dfm` is specific to the VCL framework, which is Windows only. You'll need to implement this code in a Firemonkey application instead.

Comment: @JerryDodge - What is Firemonkey? With a similar (Unit1.pas and Unit1.fmx) I am able to load it into Android)

Comment: Based on both this and your previous question, I **highly** recommend you research a lot more before diving in and then asking questions when you have problems.

Comment: If you use Delphi, and especially if you intend to target Android, you **MUST** know what Firemonkey is. That's the whole framework you're using. Traditional Delphi uses the VCL framework which is Windows only, but FMX (Firemonkey) is the new framework which can target multiple platforms. You can't mix the two. I mean you can technically, but that's a whole different story which is irrelevant to your case.

Comment: @JerryDodge - Based on this documentation I have used a `Multi Device Form` and that particular example does work on Android

Comment: The form isn't what's important. The important part is the type of application you're writing. The fact that your code is looking for a `dfm` file tells me you're attempting to write a VCL Forms application, which is for Windows only. You need to start a new Firemonkey Multi-Platform application from scratch instead, and re-write your above code there. But again, you have a lot of learning to do before you should dive in this deep. You're diving into the deep end before you even know how to tread water, and you will surely drown.

Comment: A Google search on *What is a Delphi DFM file* turned up [this](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions) as the very first result. You might try something like that in the future. I got it in less time than it took you to post your comments here to Jerry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what I see in your code, you are working with a `VCL Forms Application`, which is for Windows only. Yet you say you are targeting Android. There are multiple issues here, so I'll start from the top.

**E1026 File not found Unit2.dfm**

I do not see any reference to `Unit2` in your code. There is nothing here which suggests that such a file even exists in the first place. Your unit above is `TCPServer.pas` and I don't see `Unit2` in any `uses` clause. If I had to guess, this unit was originally named `Unit2.pas` but you modified the name at the very top of the unit to `TCPServer` without instructing the project of your name change.

**I am attempting to get it to compile on a Android device.**

You are going about the wrong way if this is your intention. Your above unit is for a `VCL` application, but `VCL` is for Windows only. It will not work on any mobile platform, period.

**I would like to know what is a dfm file. How is it different from a fmx file**

A `DFM` file is tied to a `VCL` application, which is how I know that's what your current project is targeting. An `FMX` file is tied to a Firemonkey application, which is what you will need to target multi-platform. You cannot mix the two together in the same application if you're targeting mobile platforms. Both `DFM` and `FMX` are the files which contain the form's design (as opposed to the code), and it differs between the two frameworks.

**I am brand new to delphi programming.**

I highly advise that you step back and go read up on Delphi first before you try to begin coding, especially if you're targeting a mobile platform.

On another note, your unit refers to `FMX` units in its uses clause, but look at the line which says `{$R *.dfm}`. This means it's looking for a `DFM` file instead. I don't know how you acquired this code, but it's a huge mix-up and is impossible to compile under either framework.